# Remove all All Elements not working

Tags: c#, list, collections

I noticed this function in a .NET project I am working on.

```
    private static void RemoveAllElements(ref List<int> listToBeRemoved)
    {
        foreach (var i in listToBeRemoved)
        {
            listToBeRemoved.Remove(i);
        }
    }
```

Is this the quickest way to remove all elements from a list? I also noticed this function doesn't catch any exceptions. Should I change this? This is in existing code.

Comment: Does this even work?  I didn't think you could modify a list inside of a loop like that.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. It will throw `InvalidOperationException` since you modify the collection while iterating.

Comment: It is in code. I will have to check if it is being called at all.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't just simplify it to

```
listToBeRemoved.Clear();
```

You can see the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a.aspx) for further details.

I don't think you need to add any exception handling logic. The `Clear` method internally uses `Array.Clear`, which as a reliability contract of Success and WillNotCorruptState. I couldn't imagine how that would throw an exception.

Answer (score 8):

```
list.Clear()
```

See the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a.aspx

Changing the collection that you are enumerating makes the enumerator invalid, so this is very bad practice. See the remarks on [List.GetEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yss765.aspx):

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains
>   unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding,
>   modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably
>   invalidated and its behavior is undefined.

The `Clear` method itself will not throw an exception, but if `listToBeRemoved` is `null`, you will get a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 5):

why not:

```
listToBeRemoved.Clear();
```

Answer (score 3):

How about the built-in [`Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a.aspx) method instead?

Not only is your `RemoveAllElements` method completely unnecessary - it doesn't even work!

Runnning the following code will generate an `InvalidOperationException` with the message *"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."*

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
list.RemoveAllElements();
```

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way is `listToBeRemoved.Clear()`.

Also there is no reason for that method to use `ref` as it does nothing to the parameter reference (just to the list referenced by the parameter). You may not be able to change this though with existing code as removing `ref` would require changes at the calling locations.

Comment: The funny part is that in this solution, I don't see it getting called at all.

Comment: Well, in that case, as the method is marked `private` you can be quite certain that you can excise the entire method from the class.

Answer (score -1):

```
static void Main (){
List<string> words = new List<string>();
words.AddRange(new[] { "banana", "plum", "peach" });

condition = words.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < condition; i++) words.RemoveAt(0);}
//it returns empty list
```

Comment: This question asks for quickest/easiest way to remove all elements from the list. Could you explain why you think that your answer is significantly different from earlier answers?

Comment: No it is not quickest way, but only one of the possibilities. Of course quickest way to remove all items from the list is to use Clear() method.

Comment: I think you need to explain in which case one should prefer your solution. Otherwise it's not clear why did you post it.

Answer (score -1):

```
static void Main ()
{
    List<string> words = new List<string>();
    words.AddRange(new[] { "banana", "plum", "peach" });
    words.RemoveAll(s=>s.Any());//This code returns empty list
 }
```